# Sprite always starts flipped

Tags: unity, 2d

Everytime I start the game, or I swap animator controllers in the inspector (in runtime), the character is flipped in X axis until I start moving him.

How do I prevent this to happen? This happens to me everytime I start a new project and I grow tired of this.

---

### Update

8 animations which are all idle ones of just 1 frame

- Down
- DownRight
- Right
- UpRight
- Up

The last 3 have the Sprite Renderer's **flipX** enabled within their animations:

- UpLeft
- Left
- DownLeft

In the middle of the transitions, sprite remains flipped until it reaches 1 or -1.

I recorded recently a video to display the issue.

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dC09snKvHAM

Same as above but in 1080p and showing entire Unity window.

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ww3GkUvb7bc

---

### 2nd update

PlayerControls.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerControls : MonoBehaviour {

    Rigidbody2D rb;
    PlayerStats pStats;
    Animator anim;

    void Awake () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        pStats = GetComponent<PlayerStats>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") > 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, pStats.pMoveSpeed, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") < 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, -pStats.pMoveSpeed, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(-pStats.pMoveSpeed, rb.velocity.y, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(pStats.pMoveSpeed, rb.velocity.y, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetButton("Vertical") || Input.GetButton("Horizontal"))
        {
            anim.SetFloat("OrientationY", Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
            anim.SetFloat("OrientationX", Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"));
        }
    }
}
```

PlayerStats.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerStats : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string pName;
    public string pClass;
    public int pLevel;
    public float pExperience;
    public float pBasicDamage;
    public float pMoveSpeed;

    public string[] pClassList;

    Animator anim;
    public RuntimeAnimatorController[] animCtrl;

    void Awake()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        pLevel = 1 + (int)pExperience / 240;

        if (!CheckAssignedClass())
        {
            pClass = "Warrior";
            Debug.LogWarning("Player class not found. Using 'Warrior' as default.");
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J))
        {
            SetClass(pClass);
        }

    }

    bool CheckAssignedClass()
    {
        bool found = false;
        var i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < pClassList.Length; i++)
        {
            if (pClassList[i] == pClass)
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            else { found = false; }
        }
        return found;
    }

    void SetClass(string className)
    {
        switch (className) {
            case "Warrior": {
                    anim.runtimeAnimatorController = animCtrl[0];
                    break;
                }
            case "Archer": anim.runtimeAnimatorController = animCtrl[1]; break;
            case "Mage": anim.runtimeAnimatorController = animCtrl[2]; break;
            default: anim.runtimeAnimatorController = animCtrl[0]; break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please explain more about it or share your script.is this problem in all your sprite or just in specific sprite? check your flipX in SpriteRenderer or transform.rotation.x

Comment: I guess you should check the direction of your gameobject which the sprites are applied to. More information on your current gameobject setup would be nice

Comment: Can you post some screenshots about your sprite and gameobject settings? And show us the code piece you use to move your sprite.

Comment: I uploaded a video to summarize what is going on. Code added as well.